# T Generics not working with builder pattern

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to use the builder pattern and I have run into a need I have not hit before. I am trying to incorporate generics into the builder options.

```
public class ObjectBuilder
{
   private object_collectionModelType;
   //private Type_collectionModelType;


    public void Build()
    {
        var x = CreateCollection<typeof(_collectionModelType)>(...);
    }


  //helper
  private Collection<T> CreateCollection<T>(...)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

It does not like me passing the _collectionModelType the error is:

> _collectionModelType is a field but used as a type.

Well yes visual studio compiler you are correct and I want to fix it but don't know how?

Somehow I need the builder to allow a base object or a System.Type to be passed in as part of the configuration, assigned to the private backing field, and then used in the Build method.

Comment: Do keep in mind that C# is a statically-typed language. It would be impossible for the compiler to provide a static type for `x` in this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't this suffice?

```
public void Build<CMT>()
{
    var x = CreateCollection<CMT>(...);
}
```

If you don't want to specify the type in the `Build()` method you can do this:

```
public class ObjectBuilder<CMT>
{

    public void Build()
    {
        var x = CreateCollection<CMT>(...);
    }
```

That would work just the same, but you have to specify the type when you create the `ObjectBuilder` with a constructor and the `ObjectBuilder` instance won't be able to change, so only that one `CMT` would be possible to build.

If you want something more flexible look at the Factory pattern or the Abstract Factory pattern. Both are very powerful if implemented correctly, with a generic interface.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this, I tested this and it is working. I'm not sure if you are looking for this.

```
namespace StackOverFlow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ObjectBuilder<string> stringObjectBuilder = new ObjectBuilder<string>();
            Collection<string> stringCol = stringObjectBuilder.Build();
            foreach (string s in stringCol) Console.WriteLine(s);
            ObjectBuilder<double> doubleObjectBuilder = new ObjectBuilder<double>();
            Collection<double> doubleCol = doubleObjectBuilder.Build();
            foreach (double d in doubleCol) Console.WriteLine(d);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
    public class ObjectBuilder<T>
    {
        private object _collectionModelType;
        //private Type_collectionModelType;
        public ObjectBuilder()
            {

            }

        public Collection<T> Build()
        {
            //_collectionModelType = collectionTypeToBuild;
            var x = CreateCollection();
            return x;
        }


        //helper
        private Collection<T> CreateCollection()
        {
            Collection<T> objCol = new Collection<T>();
            objCol.Add(default(T));
            return  objCol;
        }
    }
}
```